# How to get a Google API credentials for testing the Drive API in a Java EE Web Application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, google-drive-api, credentials

I'm developing a web application using the Enterprise Edition of Java where I need the Google Drive API. And at some point, I need to get clients "authorization" to access their Drive and for that (according to what I understood), I need to obtain Google API credentials (the oAuth ones) but this is a long process and as I'm doing this a school project, I can't wait. So I need a way to test the API without having to go through the heavy process of obtaining the credentials needed for published apps.

I am testing the Drive API on this project https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/drive-cmdline-sample

the problem is in this function

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(testApi.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.out.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=drive "
          + "into drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      System.exit(1);
    }
```

I need to somehow obtain `client_secrets.json` but I can't without credentials or at least, that's what I understood from the researches and reading I did.

This function is imported from `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;` if that helps.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, you need to authenticate in order to use Google Drive API. Otherwise, the service can not tell who is accessing/requesting data and if this person has access to it.

Don’t worry, you don’t have to wait, however you do have to perform certain steps in order to get this credential. I understand that you want to grant access by other clients to get their information with this API.

In order to do this, you first need a GCP project with the Drive API enabled. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

By clicking on “Enable the Drive API” will automatically create a project, most likely called quickstart with the Drive API already enabled.

Then you have to set up a service account to access to this project.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Once this is done, the file that will be downloaded are the credentials that you need in order to authenticate. (“client_secret.json”)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if I did it correctly, but I followed your instructions, along the way I downloaded two files (not sure which one is supposed to be the "client_secret.json" and I've been trying to find where to put it and I can't find the correct directory ... Can you help me on this issue so I can validate my work ?

Comment: The first file its created when you click “Enable the Drive API”, this is only needed if you want to use this as web API request. However, for what you want to achieve, you have to use the credentials for the service account https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

The name of the file (depending the name of the service account) <name_of_your_service_acc>-IDnumbers.json.

NOTE: Please, do NOT share the json file of your service account to anybody, with this you are granting access to your information.